# How relevant is cache locality for writes?

Tags: optimization

Assumptions:
(1) A program that writes in a large WORD array. 
(2) The array fits in a memory page. 
(3) The control loop is written in a way favorable to branch prediction. (4) The program runs on a mass market CPU for desktops (i.e. common architecture).

Questions:
(1) Is spacial distance important for writes?
(2) is it more efficient to read close to the write, or vice versa?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> (1) Is spacial distance important for writes?

Mostly likely, yes. Typically for a write the CPU has to fetch the whole cache line (same as it would for a read) and then modify a smaller part of the cache line.

Also don't forget that there's usually some kind of "virtual address -> physical address" translation going on, where these translations are likely to be cached (e.g. with TLBs/Translation Lookaside Buffers) and where a subsequent access (of any type - read or write) to the same page recycles the previously fetched translation.

> (2) is it more efficient to read close to the write, or vice versa?

Mostly likely, yes. Same reasons as above.